# Classification of extensions of representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

This is Problem 2.21 (d)in [this book](http://math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf) by Etingof etc.

Let $W, V$ are finite dimensional irreducible representations of an algebra $A$. For any $f \in \mathrm{Ext}^1(W, V)$. let $U_f$ be the corresponding extension, which is given by for $a\in A$
$$\rho_U(a)=\begin{pmatrix}
  \rho_V(a) & f(a)\\
  0& \rho_W(a)
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Show that $U_f$ is isomorphic to $U_{f'}$ as representations if and only if $f$ and $f'$ are proportional.

I proved that if $f$ and $f'$ are proportional, then they are isomorphic. But I cannot prove the converse. Any help is appreciated.

---